# Undefined variable, how to retrieve data from database in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, variables, model-view-controller, undefined

My model is:

```
function get_all_pages(){
     $query= $this->db->query("SELECT Title FROM news");
     return $query->result_array();
}
```

My view is:

```
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $count=1;
        if(!empty($content)) {
            foreach ($content as $content1)
            {
        ?>
            <tr>                                
                <td align="left"><?php echo $content1['Title']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php 
             }
         } else{?>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" colspan="4"><?php echo "No Record Added Yet!!!";?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </table>
```

My controller is:

```
public function manage_news() 
    {    
$this->load->model('users_model');
$result_nb = $this->users_model->get_all_pages();
        $data['content'] =  $result_nb; 
        $data['page_title']="Manage Pages";
        $this->load->view("manage_news",$data);
   }
```

I am using codeigniter. my exact error is:

```
Call to undefined method users_model::get_all_pages()
```

how can i fix this error? i want the title row data to appear in a table (from the db)

Comment: In your controller, what do you get if you do `echo '<pre>'; var_dump($this->data['posts']); die ();` before loading your view?

Comment: Can you do in your view var_dump posts and give the result

Comment: i tried that. exact same error appears. Message: Undefined variable: posts

Comment: it says  Message: Undefined variable: posts. NULL

Comment: I think the error should be in selecting data from DB, as you are only selecting "Title" from DB table and trying to use `$post->time` as well, which wont be returned after query execution.

Comment: i removed that so my query is: query= $this->db->query("SELECT Title FROM news");
return $query->result_array(); but now i am getting:  Call to undefined method users_model::get_all_pages()

Comment: Try to `echo 1;exit;` within your model and check are you getting `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: use Correct naming structure for CI? Which version do u use?

Filename
models/user_model.php

## Examples (for demo purpose)

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {

 // example one
 function get_all_pages() {
  
  $query =  $this->db->query("SELECT Title FROM news")->result_array();
  return ( is_array($query) && sizeof($query) > 0 ? $query : FALSE);
 }

 // example second
 function get_all_pages_second() {
  
  $data = FALSE;
  $query =  $this->db->query("SELECT Title FROM news");
   
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
   $data = $query->result_array();

  }
 
 return $data;
 
 } 

 // example third
 function get_all_pages_third() {
  
  $data = FALSE;
  $query =  $this->db->select('Title')->get('news');

  if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $data = $query->result_array();
  }

  return $data;

 }  

}
```